Azure ML Online Endpoint Scoring with Multipart data
I'm running an Azure ML managed online deployment to handle multipart form data (specifically images), but I don't know how to do it.
AzureML expects a run(data) function, which by default handles JSON inputs. My use case requires handling multipart form data instead. When deploying without modification to run(data), I received the following message in the logs:
2024-10-01 18:28:20,837 I [108] azmlinfsrv.user_script - run() is not decorated. Server will invoke it with the input in JSON string.

Based on this, I tried using the @input_schema decorator to specify that the input is of type multipart/form-data. Here’s the approach I tried:
from azureml_inference_server_http import input_schema

@input_schema('data', type='bytes', content_type='multipart/form-data')
def run(data):
    # Logic to process multipart form data
    ...

However, this caused the following error:
NameError: name 'input_schema' is not defined

Questions:
1.  How can I configure the run(data) function to properly handle multipart form data in AzureML Online Deployments?
2.  Is the @input_schema decorator deprecated, or is there another way to properly handle multipart data input in the run() function?
3.  Would switching to a custom inference server using Flask (use_custom_app: true) be a better approach? If so, can it integrate with AzureML’s run() method or must I handle the entire routing manually?

I’ve seen AzureML mostly expect JSON input, so any guidance or examples on handling multipart form-data (especially images) would be really helpful.
Thanks!

It all depends on your model. You pre process the image and store the inputs for your model in JSON file. Then make request to endpoint providing JSON file.

Provided the solution below. Check if it is working or not.

It all depends on your model and the training data you trained the model.
Below is the sample scoring code where the model needs tensors as input.
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import transforms
import json
import logging


def init():
    """
    This function is called when the container is initialized/started, typically after create/update of the deployment.
    You can write the logic here to perform init operations like caching the model in memory
    """
    global model
    # AZUREML_MODEL_DIR is an environment variable created during deployment.
    # It is the path to the model folder (./azureml-models/$MODEL_NAME/$VERSION)
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "outputs", "model.pt")
    # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
    model = torch.load(model_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
    logging.info("Init complete")


def run(input_data):
    input_data = torch.tensor(json.loads(input_data)["data"])

    # get prediction
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_data)
        classes = ["chicken", "turkey"]
        softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        pred_probs = softmax(output).numpy()[0]
        index = torch.argmax(output, 1)

    result = {"label": classes[index], "probability": str(pred_probs[index])}
    return result

And invoking the endpoint using the image like below.
def preprocess(image_file):
    """Preprocess the input image."""
    data_transforms = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.Resize(256),
            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
        ]
    )

    image = Image.open(image_file)
    image = data_transforms(image).float()
    image = torch.tensor(image)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    return image.numpy()


image_data = preprocess("test_img.jpg")
input_data = json.dumps({"data": image_data.tolist()})
with  open("request.json", "w") as  outfile:
    outfile.write(input_data)
    
result = ml_client.online_endpoints.invoke(
    endpoint_name=online_endpoint_name,
    request_file="request.json",
    deployment_name=online_deployment_name,
)

print(result)

Here, the image is preprocessed to convert it to tensors and saved in json file and the same json file is passed when invoking the endpoint.
Similarly, according to your model input you preprocess the image and send it as json file.
If you invoking the endpoint using rest api follow this document for passing json file.
also, if done training job in azure ml you can find the scoring script under trained mode output folder of you training component like shown below.

When you register this model it automatically takes this scoring script.
